# how to switch video quality on video player using variant playlist

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming

help! can you give me pointer on how to switch on videos inside variant playlist. after i segment and create variant playlist i don't know how to do this.

which is better to use MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayer??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most (simple) projects, I would recommend using MPMoviePlayerController over AVPlayer as it is very simple to use and with just a few lines of code, you get a full-fledged media player.

One big advantage of AVPlayer over MPMoviePlayerController would for example be its extended version, AVQueuePlayer as that one is able to do gapless playback of multiple movie sources. Another advantage certainly is the feature rich AVFoundation framework allowing you to do things like on-the-fly movie composition / encoding / converting. Another huge advantage of AVPlayer is the fact that you may actually play multiple video sources concurrently (e.g. side by side) without any problem.

So,depending on the project requirements we can choose the player. In this context i would suggest AVPlayer.

AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality

AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality

AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality...you can use these to change the quality of the video

Comment: @revanth , `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality `,`AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality `,`AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality ` are for exporting a video file. These are not parameters of a video player.